# Slow Steam Downloads in Ubuntu

Tags: steam

Downloads in Steam are super slow, often less than 1kb/sec.  I know that this is not due to poor steam server location or poor internet connection, as it downloads fine on Windows.  I am using Wubi.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the Ubuntu Steam client has a fixable bug where it is asking for way too much DNS information.  See here for fix

http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/2/616189106498372437/

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is not Ubuntu. I have the same issue on Mac OS and sometimes even on Windows.
Change the Download-Server-location inside Steam and try again.